# Is there some workaround to cast to a generic base class without knowing what the defined element type is?

Tags: swift, generics, swift3

I am trying to achieve a design where I can have a base class that has a generic property that I can change values on by conforming to a protocol.

```
protocol EnumProtocol {
    static var startValue: Self { get }
    func nextValue() -> Self
}

enum FooState: EnumProtocol {
    case foo1, foo2
    static var startValue: FooState { return .foo1 }
    func nextValue() -> FooState {
        switch self {
        case .foo1:
            return .foo2
        case .foo2:
            return .foo1
        }
    }
}

enum BarState: EnumProtocol {
    case bar
    static var startValue: BarState { return .bar }
    func nextValue() -> BarState {
        return .bar
    }
}


class BaseClass<T: EnumProtocol> {
    var state = T.startValue
}

class FooClass: BaseClass<FooState> {
}

class BarClass: BaseClass<BarState> {
}
```

Is it possible to end up with a solution similar to this where the element type is unknown and the value relies on the `nextValue()` method.

```
let foo = FooClass()
let bar = BarClass()
if let test = bar as? BaseClass {
    test.state = test.state.nextValue()
}
```

This works but `BarState` will be unknown in my case and a lot of classes will be subclasses of BaseClass and have different state types.

```
let bar = BarClass()
if let test = bar as? BaseClass<BarState> {
    test.state = test.state.nextValue()
}
```

This is a simplified example. In my case I will get a SKNode subclass that has a state property that is an enum with a nextvalue method that have defined rules to decide what the next value will be. I am trying to have a generic implementation of this that only relies on what is returned from the nextValue method. Is there a better pattern to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This will not work for this exact scenario because `EnumProtocol` can not be used as concrete type since it has a `Self` type requirement, however, in order to achieve this type of behavior in other cases you can create a protocol that the base class conforms to and try to cast objects to that type when you are trying to determine if an object is some subclass of that type.

Consider the following example

```swift
class Bitcoin { }

class Ethereum { }

class Wallet<T> {
    var usdValue: Double = 0
}

class BitcoinWallet: Wallet<Bitcoin> {

}

class EthereumWallet: Wallet<Ethereum> {

}

let bitcoinWallet = BitcoinWallet() as Any

if let wallet = bitcoinWallet as? Wallet {
    print(wallet.usdValue)
}
```

This will not work, due to the same error that you are referring to:

```
error: generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'Wallet<_>'
```

However, if you add the following protocol

```swift
protocol WalletType {
    var usdValue: Double { get set }
}
```

and make `Wallet` conform to that

```swift
class Wallet<T>: WalletType
```

then you can cast values to that protocol and use it as expected:

```swift
if let wallet = bitcoinWallet as? WalletType {
    print(wallet.usdValue)
}
```